# Achieving diagonal movement when 2 arrow keys are pressed (with SFML)

Tags: c++, sfml

I do not think any code demonstrations will be necessary because it's not much SFML as it is C++. The question is, how would I achieve smooth movement with something that I'm blitting on the screen? For example, I blit a square to the screen, and I make it's position variables as integers that I've defined before so that I can move it with my arrow keys. When I press the keys that add values to the variables it works fine if I use only one key, but upon pressing two keys, it only adds to the value that was pressed second. How would I make it so it moves diagonally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pseudo-code

```
if (key.up())
{
    if (key.right())
        direction = up_right;
    else if (key.left())
        direction = up_left;
    else
        direction = up;
}
else if (key.down())
{
    etc...
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer isn't that great.

You are better off storing the x and y movement separately, checking all the keys that have been pressed and then assigning the actual movement.

```
x = 0.0;
y = 0.0;
speed = 1.0;

if (key.up())
{
  y -= speed;
}

if (key.down())
{
  y+= speed;
}

if (key.left())
{
  x -= speed;
}

if (key.right())
{
  x+= speed;
}

Move(x, y);
```

That should get you started.

As you look more into it, you will notice this code has a little quirk - if you move diagonally you'll find you are moving a bit too quickly and cheating a bit!  This is because two units of speed are being added, not just one.  You might think the solution is to halve each value but then you will be too sluggish.  When you're moving diagonally you need to think in triangles and of the Pythagoras theorem - you'll want to compensate by dividing both directions by root 2.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but like you said the player could gain an unfair advantage by having a more modern computer. I took the square root of the variables x and y but I'm not sure this is preventing any kind of unwanted cheating.

```
float x = 0.0;
float y = 0.0;
float speed = 0.35;

x = std::sqrt(std::pow((double)x, 2) + std::pow((double)y, 2));
y = std::sqrt(std::pow((double)x, 2) + std::pow((double)y, 2));

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
{
        source.y = Up;
        y -= speed;
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
{
        source.y = Down;
        y += speed;
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
{
        source.y = Left;
        x -= speed;
}

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
{
        source.y = Right;
        x += speed;
}

playerImage.move(x, y);
```

Also I have an instance after my event loop that compares frame counter to clock and frame speed. My question is this, would this block have an effect on the above code possible preventing the cheating, if so would i remove the sqrt statements?

```
frameCounter = (updateFrame) ? frameCounter + frameSpeed * clock.restart().asSeconds() : 0;

if(frameCounter >= switchFrame)
{
        frameCounter = 0;
        source.x++;
        if(source.x * 32 >= pTexture.getSize().x)
                source.x = 0;
}
```